# How to store data from API so that it can be accessible in other components

Tags: reactjs, wp-api

I am doing a project with React.js and Wordpress REST API. All this time I have been using axios to get the data from API whenever the component mounts. This means that every single time I render a component that has to display some data I make an API request. The project is scaling up and I realized that this way of doing things is not the best.

How should I deal with this problem? Should I use Redux? I think Redux is an overkill for this since I will not modify the data, I will only display it. Should I use React Context API?

If any code needed, I will add.

Comment: React itself lets you manage state using either class components or `useState`. So, all you really need to do is have some state living at a common ancestor of any component that needs the API data and store the data there, passing down any needed information as props.

Comment: But what If I use React Router to navigate through my app?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, you can still pass data to routes using render props: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/

Answer (score 4):

I think redux is the best solution to keep your project scalable and well organized, but if you don't want to use it, you can try with context, keep in mind that it means that you must call your api in a high level component.

**Here's a sample of your app component with the context definition:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const DataContext = React.createContext({})

const App = () => {
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(endPoint).then(response => setApiResponse(response))
  },[]);

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={apiResponse}>
      <YourAppContent />
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App
```

**Every time you need to get your API data:**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import { DataContext } from '../App';

const UserCard = () => {
  const data = useContext(DataContext);
  const { user } = data || {};
  return <Card>{user.fullName}</Card>
}

export default UserCard
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I am going to use Context API.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a relatively simple application state and you only want to display data. I think to use Context API is a suitable approach.

**For Simple State**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from 'react';
// some sort of libs that fetchs data for you.
import FetchService from './util/FetchService';

const OrderInfoContext = createContext();

// This is a helper component that generates the Provider wrapper
function OrderInfoProvider(props) {
  // We will persist API payload in the state so we can assign it to the Context
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);


  // We use useEffect to make API calls.
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      // This is just a helper to fetch data from endpoints. It can be done using axios or similar libraries
      const orders = await FetchService
        .get('/v1/registry/orders');
      setOrders(orders);
    }
    fetchData();
  });
  //we create a global object that is avaibvale to every child components 
  return <OrderInfoContext.Provider value={[orders, setOrders]} {...props} />;
}

// Helper function to get Context
function useOrderInfo() {
  const context = useContext(OrderInfoContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useOrderInfo must be used within a OrderInfoProvider');
  }
  return context;
}

export { OrderInfoProvider, useOrderInfo };
```

**For Slightly Complex State**

As your app gets a bit more complicated. You can still use the same approach with `useReducer` hook

```js
// reducer returns the next state based on the action passed in
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INITIAL:
      return [];
    case FETCH_ORDER:
      return action.payload;
    case ADD_ORDER:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

// This is a helper component that generate the Provider wrapper
function OrderInfoProvider(props) {
  // We will persist API payload in the state so we can assign it to the Context
  const [orders, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);
  const addOrderInfo = (data) => { addOrders(dispatch, data); };

  async function fetchOrders() {
    const data = await ApiService
      .get('/v1/registry/orders');
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_ORDER,
      payload: data
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchOrders();
  }, []);

  // we create a global object that is available to every child components
  return <OrderInfoContext.Provider value={[orders, dispatch]} {...props} />;
}
```

**For Complex State**

You should definitely consider using Redux as the other answer suggested. The Redux dev tool can save you lots of debugging time.

**Reference**

I took the code from a couple of articles I wrote some times ago. You can probably find a better explanation there.

https://tech.zola.com/practical-use-cases-of-react-context-and-hooks-a9f62815e38d

https://www.andrew-zheng.com/blog/use-reducer

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I am going to use Context API.